# Why does maven/junit only print the "bottommost" line of a stack trade when an exception is thrown?

Tags: maven, junit

I'm seeing some odd behavior in the output of failed tests when using JUnit with maven.  Specifically, the stack trace printed for a RuntimeException only has the "bottommost"/deepest line printed.

For example:

```
[INFO] Running com.foo.MyTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.59 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.foo.MyTest
[ERROR] testBar(com.foo.MyTest)  Time elapsed: 0.588 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.foo.MyTest.testBar(MyTest.java:132)
```

The problem is that the NPE doesn't occur on line 132 of MyTest.java.  There, I call something, which calls something else, and so on, and about 10 method calls *later* is my NPE.  It's almost if they take the whole stack trace and throw out everything except the first method call in it.  This makes it impossible to debug where the actual exception is being thrown of course.

I am running the tests with the command `mvn package assembly:single`.  Running with the -e flag ("To see the full stack trace of the errors") only prints "internal" stack traces like the following without any of my code:

```
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException (SurefireHelper.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:364)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1041)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Is something misconfigured somewhere?  Happy to provide more info to debug if it's necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a configuration `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>`. https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace which is by default `true`... furthermore calling maven-assembly-plugin manually via goal is a bad thing better integrate maven-assembly-plugin into the life cycle to final go via `mvn clean package`...

Comment: @khmarbaise - thank you!!! this was driving me insane.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.  Why on earth would anyone want to exclude the part of the stack trace that actually shows where their problem is???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a configuration `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>` https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace which is by default `true`